# Issue with the word order in a sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis, word-order

This sentence:

> Please indicate the best date, time and time zone for us to start the upgrade in your response.

seems to have an incorrect word order.

I have no idea how to fix things up without removing anything.

Could someone give me a hint please?

Comment: "Please indicate in your response the best date and time to start the upgrade. Please include time zone if specifying local time or use UCT (Universal Coordinated Time)."

Answer (score 0):

You're asking someone to choose a date and time, which is fine, but you're also asking them to **choose** a time zone.  This isn't correct - people don't choose a time zone, they're just in one whether they like it or not.

So, you need them to **choose** a date and time, and **tell** you what time zone they're in, so you can adjust that date and time to your own local time.

"to start the upgrade in your response." seems fairly nonsensical to me - I don't know what you're trying to say so I'm just going to leave it alone.

So, I'd say something like

*"Please inform us of your time zone and indicate the best date and time for us to start the upgrade in your response.  "*